# Best way to calculate weight of all rows in a table for sorting?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, web

There's a products table

```sql
table products
id    favorite_count    saved_count    weight
1     50                9              2.01
2     80                20             3.3
```

There are several formulas available for calculating weights base on the favorite_count and saved_count, and the calculation process might be complex, potentially consuming significant computational resources.

When is the most appropriate time to calculate these weights? Is it during the insertion and updating of data, or is it after querying the data?

Calculating weights during the insertion and updating of data might limit me to using a single formula, given that the weight calculation formula is a variable. In other words, it would restrict me to a single sorting algorithm.

Due to the sorting operation involved, calculating weights after the query seems to require retrieving the entire table data each time, which clearly would consume significant computational resources.

Or should I consider implementing a caching solution, such as using Redis, where I pre-calculate and store the results of each type of sorting in different temporary databases? Then, based on the sorting type, perform queries in the respective database?

I've tried calculating weights after query the whole table, and then sorting the data base on weight, but it's really slow as the data increase.

Comment: How would we know what your calculation options are? Nor how many rows you might have in any table? There just isn't enough details to answer and all we could do is offer an opinion. What methods have you tried? What testing have you done?

Comment: Calculating weights during the insertion and updating of data might limit me to using a single formula << Why?

Comment: @HeinzSiahaan The sorting is based on weights, if the weights are determined during insertion, it limits sorting to a single form. However, calculating weights during queries doesn't rely on the weight field in the table. Instead, it calculates weights in real-time based on the selected formula and sorts data accordingly, allowing for multiple sorting outcomes.

Comment: If you have multiple formulae for calculating weight and they have different results, you might choose to store them in separate fields when first creating the record. You can then choose which weight field to use when you're extracting the data.

Comment: It sounds like there are multiple issues:  
* Is it inefficient to calculate weight every time that you read the database?  
* Is it inefficient to calculate weight before inserting a record into the database? Because there are multiple formulae for calculating weight, the query operation might never use the inserted weight value anyway because it wants to calculate with a different formula.  
* Is it violating the third normal form to have a weight field that is derived from the two count fields? You could use a TRIGGER to ensure that the weights are up-to-date after every record update.